# Split Cell At The First Instance of any Letter in Excel

Tags: excel

So I have cells that I need to split like this:

#*  Mother care P.L.C...............................    614,311    1,656,049

I Only need the name and the two values in different cells like this:

**Column A** - Mother care P.L.C.
**Column B** - 614,311
**Column C** - 1,656,049

The length of name and characters before it varies, also if you have idea how could I split the two values that would be splendid!

I have tried splitting it in fixed width mode, but they are just a mess.

Comment: Is this programming-related? If so, please show what you have tried so that we can help fix it. If not, it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivially possible with standard Excel functions.
You could write a [User Defined Function](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel) in VB but then your workbook should be an `Excel Macro-enabled Workbook (.xlsm)`.